# Gradle 'project name' project refresh failed, Error: Connect timed out: conect

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> I already made changes in Settings ->HTTP Proxy-> Auto-detect proxy
>    settings but not working.
>   I have this problem after i am update my android studio to 2.3.3.
>
> I already checked with old version of android studio but now it does
>    not work.

**When Gradle tasks Clean:-**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'AllCartSearch'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

**Here is the log after gradle sync error:-**
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:82)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 144 more
2017-06-20 15:57:53,574 [1049961]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Connection timed out: connect 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:86)

Comment: Have you checked your internet connectivity?

Comment: @Jeffrey internet is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem come from the antivirus specially Avast Antivirus, disable it and try again.